# Bootstrap button gets stuck together

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

When I put button on table it gets stuck together [image: like this]

```
<tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>755535</td>
            <td>The there is no difference:</td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs col-md-12 col-lg-12">Update</button> <br>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs col-md-12 col-lg-12">Delete</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
```

How can I put a space between these two buttons. br tag is not working. If I put two br tags then it gets more space.

Comment: Add some padding then?

Comment: button gets thicker

Comment: add a css rule `button:first-child { margin-bottom: 2px; }` or inline style the first button `style="margin-bottom: 2px;"`

Comment: I edited my answer should work now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this.

```css
.margin-bottom {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-sm-4">

  <button type="button" class="margin-bottom btn btn-info btn-xs col-md-12 col-lg-12">Update</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs col-md-12 col-lg-12">Delete</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It's only required on the first button.

Answer (score 0):

try with

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs col-md-12 col-lg-12">Update</button>
</div>
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs col-md-12 col-lg-12">Delete</button>
</div>
```

It should work try now.

Comment: same.... not working...........<div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs col-md-12 col-lg-12">Update</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs col-md-12 col-lg-12">Delete</button>
     </div>

Comment: @Nakul23 take a look at my code again i edited as you need

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 solutions for this.

Solution #1:

Add `width` to your td and fix your mark-up. 
[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/33902/)

```
<td width="300">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">Update</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Delete</button>
  </td>
```

Solution #2:

Use `btn-group`. [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/33903/)

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">Update</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Delete</button>
</div>
```